# jquery create 2 new elements in one variable

Tags: jquery

Can i create 2 new elements in one variable and then use .html() with this variable?
I know i can just write a string of this element like this

```
var foo = '<img class="foo" src="/foo1.jpg"><img class="foo" src="/foo2.jpg">';
$('#test').html(foo);
```

But can i do it with this syntax somehow? (This is not working)

```
var foo = $('<img>',{
    'class': 'foo',
    src: '/foo1.jpg'
}), $('<img>',{
    'class': 'foo',
    src: '/foo2.jpg'
});
$('#test').html(foo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it inside an array

```js
var foo = [$('<img>', {
  'class': 'foo',
  src: '/foo1.jpg'
}), $('<img>', {
  'class': 'foo',
  src: '/foo2.jpg'
})];

$('#test').html(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Makes sense, why didn't i think about array , tyvm